# "Return outside function" error for 'for' loop in python

Tags: python-3.x

The following code returns me an error in python saying **return outside function** while using *for* loop. Can someone please let me know where i'm doing it wrong. I'm new to python.

```
strvar=["A","B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]
for i in strvar:
    print("the perc in " + i)
    return i+1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that means is that your `return` statement is unnecessary since you are not inside of a function.

Also since you are iterating over the values of the string there is no need to increment `i` since `i` is not an integer.

instead change your code to something like this:

```
strvar=["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]
for i in strvar:
    print("the perc in " + i)
```

Comment: @arun_K  Your welcome.  please remember to mark your question as answered.  In fact you should go through your older questions and mark any of them as answered as well if appropriate.  It isn't mandatory to mark them complete but it is encouraged